# C++ use of deleted function on compile

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

`Opcodes.h`:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_OPCODES_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_OPCODES_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include "ClientOpcode.h"
#include "Server/AuthSession.h"
#include "Server/WorldSession.h"
#include "Server/Client.h"

namespace Vibranium{
    class OpcodeBase{
    public:
        OpcodeBase() = default;
        virtual ~OpcodeBase() =default;
        template<class T> const T& getType() const;
        ClientOpcode clientOpcode;
        void(AuthSession::*AuthSessionHandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet);
        void(WorldSession::*WorldSessionHandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet);
    };
    template<typename T>
    class Opcode : public OpcodeBase{
    public:
        Opcode() = default;
        const T& getType() const {return type;}

    private:
        T type;
    };
    class Opcodes {
    public:
        Opcodes() = default;
        virtual ~Opcodes() = default;
        virtual void Initialize() = 0;
        template<typename T>
        void SetAuthServerOpcode(ClientOpcode clientOpcode, void(AuthSession::*HandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet));
        template<typename T>
        void SetWorldServerOpcode(ClientOpcode clientOpcode, void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet));
        class OpcodeHandler{
        public:
            OpcodeHandler() = default;
            OpcodeBase* opcode;
            void Run(AuthSession* _session, const Packet& packet);
            void Run(WorldSession* _session, const Packet& packet);
        };

    public:
        static OpcodeHandler opcodeHandler[CLIENT_NUM_MSG_TYPES];
    };

}

template<typename T>
void Vibranium::Opcodes::SetWorldServerOpcode(ClientOpcode clientOpcode,
                                              void (WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet)) {
    Opcode<T> opcode;
    opcode.clientOpcode = clientOpcode;
    opcode.WorldSessionHandlerFunction = HandlerFunction;
    opcodeHandler[clientOpcode].opcode = &opcode;
}
template<typename T>
void Vibranium::Opcodes::SetAuthServerOpcode(ClientOpcode clientOpcode,
                                             void(AuthSession::*HandlerFunction)(const Packet& packet)) {
    Opcode<T> opcode;
    opcode.clientOpcode = clientOpcode;
    opcode.AuthSessionHandlerFunction = HandlerFunction;
    opcodeHandler[clientOpcode].opcode = &opcode;
}



#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_OPCODES_H
```

Opcodes.cpp:

```
#include "Opcodes.h"

Vibranium::Opcodes::OpcodeHandler Vibranium::Opcodes::opcodeHandler[CLIENT_NUM_MSG_TYPES];

void Vibranium::Opcodes::OpcodeHandler::Run(WorldSession *_session, const Packet& packet) {
    (_session->*opcode->WorldSessionHandlerFunction)(packet);

}

void Vibranium::Opcodes::OpcodeHandler::Run(AuthSession *_session, const Packet& packet) {
    (_session->*opcode->AuthSessionHandlerFunction)(packet);

}
```

`AuthServerOpcodes.h`:

```
#ifndef VIBRANIUM_CORE_AUTHSERVEROPCODES_H
#define VIBRANIUM_CORE_AUTHSERVEROPCODES_H

#include "Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h"

class AuthServerOpcodes : public Vibranium::Opcodes {
public:
    AuthServerOpcodes() = default;
    void Initialize() override;
};


#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_AUTHSERVEROPCODES_H
```

AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:

```
#include "AuthServerOpcodes.h"
#include "Server/AuthSession.h"
#include "Account/Account_generated.h"
#include "Connect/Connect_generated.h"

void AuthServerOpcodes::Initialize() {
#define DEFINE_HANDLER(opcode,handler, type) \
    SetAuthServerOpcode<type>(opcode, handler)

    DEFINE_HANDLER(CLIENT_AUTH_CONNECTION,&AuthSession::ConnectAuth, Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest);
    DEFINE_HANDLER(CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST,&AuthSession::Login, Vibranium::LoginRequest);
}
```

And when I try to compile this code I get the following error:

```
[ 79%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp.o
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.h:8,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:5:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vibranium::Opcodes::SetAuthServerOpcode(ClientOpcode, void (AuthSession::*)(const Vibranium::Packet&)) [with T = Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest]’:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:14:5:   required from here
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:68:15: error: use of deleted function ‘Vibranium::Opcode<T>::Opcode() [with T = Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest]’
   68 |     Opcode<T> opcode;
      |               ^~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:28:9: note: ‘Vibranium::Opcode<T>::Opcode() [with T = Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   28 |         Opcode() = default;
      |         ^~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:28:9: error: use of deleted function ‘Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest::AuthConnectionRequest()’
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:8:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/Connect/Connect_generated.h:23:8: note: ‘Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest::AuthConnectionRequest()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   23 | struct AuthConnectionRequest FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS : private flatbuffers::Table {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/Connect/Connect_generated.h:23:8: error: ‘flatbuffers::Table::Table()’ is private within this context
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packet.h:15,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/AuthSession.h:10,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:11,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.h:8,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h:2553:3: note: declared private here
 2553 |   Table();
      |   ^~~~~
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.h:8,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:5:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vibranium::Opcodes::SetAuthServerOpcode(ClientOpcode, void (AuthSession::*)(const Vibranium::Packet&)) [with T = Vibranium::LoginRequest]’:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:15:5:   required from here
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:68:15: error: use of deleted function ‘Vibranium::Opcode<T>::Opcode() [with T = Vibranium::LoginRequest]’
   68 |     Opcode<T> opcode;
      |               ^~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:28:9: note: ‘Vibranium::Opcode<T>::Opcode() [with T = Vibranium::LoginRequest]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   28 |         Opcode() = default;
      |         ^~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:28:9: error: use of deleted function ‘Vibranium::LoginRequest::LoginRequest()’
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:7:
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/Account/Account_generated.h:59:8: note: ‘Vibranium::LoginRequest::LoginRequest()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   59 | struct LoginRequest FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS : private flatbuffers::Table {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packets/Account/Account_generated.h:59:8: error: ‘flatbuffers::Table::Table()’ is private within this context
In file included from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Packet.h:15,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/AuthSession.h:10,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.h:11,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.h:8,
                 from /home/armegon/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h:2553:3: note: declared private here
 2553 |   Table();
      |   ^~~~~
make[3]: *** [Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/build.make:148: Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:332: Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:339: Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:210: AuthServer] Error 2
```

P.S.

```
struct AuthConnectionRequest FLATBUFFERS_FINAL_CLASS : private flatbuffers::Table {
  typedef AuthConnectionRequestBuilder Builder;
  bool Verify(flatbuffers::Verifier &verifier) const {
    return VerifyTableStart(verifier) &&
           verifier.EndTable();
  }
};
```

Comment: You violated the rule of five. That's very likely where your issue comes from:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three + http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Comment: `opcodeHandler[clientOpcode].opcode = &opcode;` are we storing the address of a temporary in an array here?

Comment: @drescherjm should I make `opcode` unique_ptr ?

Comment: It says the default constructor for `AuthConnectionRequest` is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed. Perhaps you should show the definition of `AuthConnectionRequest`?

Comment: @Venelin it would be a start. You probably need to change opcodeHandler as well and std::move the unique_ptr

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've added `AuthConnectionRequest` can you please check ?

Comment: After seeing the added code, I believe this means the person who answered guessed correctly.

Comment: @drescherjm That would be my impression too. Venelin: Doesn't the current answer point directly at the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first output from the compiler it tells you, that the compiler can't execute this line:

```
Opcode<T> opcode;   // where T = Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest
```

Because for `Opcode<T>` with `T=Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest` the default constructor can't be called; Given the current template type T, the default constructor would be ill-formed, and is thus deleted.

The reason the default constructor is ill-formed, is that it can't properly default construct all members of `Opcode<Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest>`. Specifically, it can't default construct an object of type `Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest`, apparently because there is no proper default constructor for `Vibranium::AuthConnectionRequest`.

The `AuthConnectionRequest` inherits privately from `Table`, and in the error message it is stated that the default constructor of `Table` needs to be called, which failed because it is private.

Here is a small example of the inheritance layout which produces the same compiler errors:
https://godbolt.org/z/3Po56P